# Why everytime i after reload/restart shell , RVM always not found

Tags: shell, rvm

for few day i have problem with my RVM whenever i restart shell and run `RVM` again it's always say `-bash: rvm: command not found` , any advice please ?

i am currently using Mac

Comment: So do you always install rvm after restart shell?

Comment: yes , but i'am alredy found the solution :D

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked for me

```
ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
[[ -s “$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm” ]] && source “$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm”
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```